# Can Lithium-Iron-Phosphate or LiFePO4 batteries be stored in cold?

Tags: batteries, lifepo4, battery-storage

According to this [site,](https://www.solacity.com/how-to-keep-lifepo4-lithium-ion-batteries-happy/) you can store in -40°C/-40°F just never charge them below freezing.

I have a E-Bike in cold Canada and taking the battery out is a pain.
The link says just make sure it's disconnected with a 50%-60% charge.

I cannot get answer on the internet. They just keep saying do not use in cold weather ONLY.  I just want to store in cold, not use the battery.

Comment: check the manufacturer datasheet

Comment: That is, the manufacturer of the *cells*, not the pack or bike. If you can't find a datasheet for those brand cells with the info you want, ask that cell manufacturer directly.

Comment: How cold is cold? There's a difference between just being cold and freezing (of the battery, not of water).

Comment: For reference, the storage temp (not operational temp) for Trojan Trillium LFP batteries is -40 to 60C. The operational temp is -20, HOWEVER, there is a note in the datasheet that charging below 23C should not be done at the full rate. https://www.trojanbattery.com/pdf/datasheets/24_Lithium_12.8-92.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Lithium batteries are powered by chemical reactions (citation needed).  As a rule of thumb, every +10C doubles the reaction rate -- which means that every -10C halves the reaction rate.  Charging a lithium battery is taxing on them as-is, and it is damaging if the electrolyte is operating at 1/64th of its usual performance (20C -> -40C).  The specific behavior is in your manufacturer's data sheet (if one exists), but it's fairly safe to say the batteries would prefer to be about room temperature.

According to https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a351962.pdf, the freeze point of conventional LiPo electrolyte is about -30C.  You run a very serious risk of internal mechanical damage in the cell below this point.  I would add 10C to this to give myself headroom.

This gives you a storage temperature of -20C to +20C at roughly 50% SoC (~ 3.8v/cell).  In this range, cooler will be better.  *But, you cannot use the cells until their internal temperature has hit operating temperature*.  This may be several minutes, or even hours, after the exterior of the cells has warmed.

TLDR: your choice is to not live in Hoth, or take your battery inside.

Comment: That paper seems to be rather old and also directed at lithium ion batteries which are not the same as LiFePO4 batteries. The datasheet for Trojan Trillium LiFePO4 batteries lists a storage temp of -40 to 60C.

Comment: That seem more like it , my question link site could not be that off the mark . There is  no moisture in a LifePO4 so it makes sense "cold not in use storage" should not hurt anything.